# A shared .so library is incompatible with "aarch64linux", when building for arm64-v8a only

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cross-compiling, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile an Android NDK application, linked against some prebuilt libraries of a vendor. I don't have their source code, so I can't rebuild those libraries, only link against them. These libraries come prebuilt for `aarch64-android-clang8.0` or `arm-android-clang8.0`.

Now the issue is that I'm trying to build an application for `arm64-v8a` ABI. I've setup a main `Android.mk` with an additional `Android.mk` to define this prebuilt library. Omitting unrelated stuff, it roughly goes like

```
# Along the lines of the main Android.mk
...
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += snpe
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../..)
$(call import-module,snpe_prebuilt/snpe)
...

# Library's Android.mk
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := snpe
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SNPE_SDK_PATH)/lib/arm-android-clang8.0/libSNPE.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

During build it throws a puzzling error:

> ld: error: <some_path>/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/arm64-v8a/libSNPE.so is incompatible with aarch64linux
>
> clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What I don't understand is why it checks the compatibility against `aarch64linux` when I never asked it. I have `APP_ABI := arm64-v8a` in my `Application.mk`, and in `build.gradle`.

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
    }
    ndkBuild {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
    }
}
ndk {
    abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
}
```

The library is indeed built for ARM, e.g. see the logs of `arm-linux-androideabi-readelf.exe` from NDK

> .\arm-linux-androideabi-readelf.exe -A <path/to/library/arm-android-clang8.0/libSNPE.so>

```
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "ARM v7"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv4
  Tag_Advanced_SIMD_arch: NEONv1 with Fused-MAC
  Tag_ABI_PCS_GOT_use: GOT-indirect
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
  Tag_FP_HP_extension: Allowed
  Tag_ABI_FP_16bit_format: IEEE 754
  Tag_Virtualization_use: TrustZone
```

What is more surprising, is that it **COMPILES**, when linking against `aarch64-android-clang8.0` flavor of the library like that

```
# Library's Android.mk
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := snpe
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SNPE_SDK_PATH)/lib/aarch64-android-clang8.0/libSNPE.so # instead of arm-android-clang8.0
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And then in the runtime some of the functions work properly while other crash with segfaults, and that's why I think that this `aarch64` library isn't a good solution.

The build command that is issued by Android Studio:

```
<some_ndk_path>\ndk\24.0.8215888\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=<some_project_path>\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=<some_project_path>\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-24 NDK_OUT=<some_project_path>/android/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=<some_project_path>\android\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib V=0 -j8 -C<some_project_path>\android APP_PLATFORM=android-24 NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang NDK_DEBUG=1 OVR_DEBUG=1 USE_ASAN=1 oculusavatar}
```

## -- Edit --

Crash trace:

```
2023-02-14 13:43:48.703 18630-18775 libc                    pid-18630                            A  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7072109ac8 in tid 18775 (OVR::Main), pid 18630 (cm.oculusavatar)
2023-02-14 13:43:48.793 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A  *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2023-02-14 13:43:48.793 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A  Build fingerprint: 'oculus/hollywood/hollywood:10/QQ3A.200805.001/37314400808900000:user/release-keys'
2023-02-14 13:43:48.793 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A  Revision: '0'
2023-02-14 13:43:48.793 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A  ABI: 'arm64'
2023-02-14 13:43:48.794 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A  Timestamp: 2023-02-14 13:43:48+0300
2023-02-14 13:43:48.794 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A  pid: 18630, tid: 18775, name: OVR::Main  >>> com.example.example <<<
2023-02-14 13:43:48.794 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A  uid: 10096
2023-02-14 13:43:48.794 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A  signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7072109ac8
2023-02-14 13:43:48.794 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A      x0  0000007060501470  x1  0000007060500798  x2  0000000000000001  x3  000000706d4ee960
2023-02-14 13:43:48.794 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A      x4  0000007060501470  x5  0000007072b05e98  x6  fefeff115c149b0a  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7fff7f
2023-02-14 13:43:48.794 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A      x8  0000007072109ac8  x9  0000000000000003  x10 0000000000004957  x11 0000000000004957
2023-02-14 13:43:48.794 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A      x12 0000000000000001  x13 0000000000000000  x14 ffffffffffffffff  x15 0000000000000050
2023-02-14 13:43:48.794 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A      x16 000000707212c478  x17 000000715b8c05a0  x18 0000000000000100  x19 0000007060500798
2023-02-14 13:43:48.794 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A      x20 000000706d4ee960  x21 0000000000000001  x22 0000000000000002  x23 0000007060501470
2023-02-14 13:43:48.795 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A      x24 0000000000000000  x25 0000007072109908  x26 0000007072109a18  x27 0000007060501838
2023-02-14 13:43:48.795 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A      x28 0000007060503018  x29 0000007060500770
2023-02-14 13:43:48.795 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A      sp  0000007060500770  lr  0000007072b0a3f8  pc  0000007072109ac8
2023-02-14 13:43:49.125 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A  
                                                                                                    backtrace:
2023-02-14 13:43:49.125 18833-18833 DEBUG                   pid-18833                            A        #00 pc 0000000000001ac8  /data/app/com.example.example-DCjlQwt6O7adQRp_vv3W8g==/base.apk
```

Comment: aarch64 is same as arm64-v8a. You should check on what architecture your library is built with. If you are building on Linux, you can use `readelf -h libname.so | grep -i "class\|machine" | head -2`. I would guess your library is built with armeabi which is probably ARM 32-bit.

Comment: @kiner_shah So you mean that `arm64-v8a` application should be linked against `aarch64-android-clang8.0` version, and, and `armeabi-v7a` application linked against `arm-android-clang8.0`? Then probably the reason of my crashes is not in a wrong library. Thank you

Comment: I indeed see `Machine: AArch64` for this `arm-android-clang8.0` flavored library

Comment: Yes, you mentioned crash, did you check logcat to see if stacktrace is logged?

Comment: @kiner_shah the logcat is not very verbose, it indicates some vendor-specific error code that is not googleable, and then a segfault in `libc`. These vendor libraries that I use also include it's own prebuilt `libc++_shared.so`, but I didn't manage to link my Android app against it. I wonder if I absolutely need to link against it or I can rely on the NDK's provided one. Anyway I think my crash is beyond this question, thank you for you comments, you can post them as an answer!

Comment: You can use new logcat. It shows complete trace. https://medium.com/@stevdza-san/new-logcat-in-android-studio-dolphin-is-amazing-cce5ffecb07b. Also, does the log contain SIGABRT or SIGSEGV?

Comment: @kiner_shah Yeah, with the new logcat the trace is a tiny bit bigger, but not much, just  `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x706ee7e908 in tid 15108 (OVR::Main), pid 15072` and a bunch of addressess like `#00 pc 0000000000001ac8  /data/app/com.blah.example-Z1enE79hKakzcp4g2iD_-A==/base.apk`. Might be related to `libc++_shared.so` after all

Comment: Better to put the entire trace you got in the question.

Comment: @kiner_shah I put it there

Comment: It's crashing. I can see `OVR::Main` maybe the crash happens there. If there were debug symbols, maybe it could show more output.

Comment: @kiner_shah doesn't seem like so. Anyway, thanks for your help. I would be grateful a thousand times more, if you could look at my [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75445644/how-to-add-a-shared-library-into-android-ndk-package-without-trying-to-link-agai) regarding building with NDK