# How to add a shared library into Android NDK package without trying to link against it

Tags: android, android-ndk, linker-errors

I have a few vendor `.so` libraries that are meant to be present in the application's `.apk`, to be loaded in runtime by Qualcomm hardware. They are not linked against any of my C++ code and are not tied to the ABI of the device (the same library files for both `arm64-v8a` and `armeabi-v7a`).

I'm not sure how to add such libraries into the application package via `Android.mk`. E.g. when I do

```
# My project
...
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += snpe_dsp_v65_domains_v2_skel

# Library definition
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := snpe_dsp_v65_domains_v2_skel
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := $(SNPE_SDK_PATH)/lib/dsp/libsnpe_dsp_v65_domains_v2_skel.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I get `libsnpe_dsp_v66_domains_v2_skel.so is incompatible with aarch64linux` error. As I understand, it tried to link against this library, which is not what I want, I only want to add it into the package. If I omit the library from `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`, it's neither linked against nor added into the package, which I checked by observing libraries at location `<project_path>\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\obj\local\arm64-v8a\`

## -- EDIT --

Alright, I indeed copied those libraries via plain Makefile `cp` command, and they're finally in the `.apk` file. I did like so in `Android.mk`.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := snpe_dsp_v65_domains_v2_skel
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SNPE_SDK_PATH)/lib/dsp/libsnpe_dsp_v65_domains_v2_skel.so
$(shell cp $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES) $(TARGET_OUT))
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Though everything except `$(shell cp $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES) $(TARGET_OUT))` is not necessary

Unfortunately, after that the vendor's code can't load them in runtime:

```
E/com.example.example: vendor/qcom/proprietary/commonsys-intf/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1844: Error: Device node open failed for domain 3 (errno Permission denied)
E/com.example.example: vendor/qcom/proprietary/commonsys-intf/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:2158: Error 0x57: apps_dev_init failed for domain 3, errno Permission denied
E/com.example.example: vendor/qcom/proprietary/commonsys-intf/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:2254: Error 0x57: open_dev (-1) failed for domain 3
E/com.example.example: vendor/qcom/proprietary/commonsys-intf/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1053: Error 0x57: remote_handle64_open failed for file:////data/app/com.example.example-qP0bP5ry9PqK3iQ1YKmeJg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libsnpe_dsp_v66_domains_v2_skel.so?snpe_dsp_domains_v2_skel_handle_invoke&_modver=1.0&_dom=cdsp
W/OVR::Main: type=1400 audit(0.0:1165): avc: denied { read } for name="adsprpc-smd-secure" dev="tmpfs" ino=1131 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:xdsp_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0
E/com.example.example: vendor/qcom/proprietary/commonsys-intf/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1844: Error: Device node open failed for domain 3 (errno Permission denied)
E/com.example.example: vendor/qcom/proprietary/commonsys-intf/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:2158: Error 0x57: apps_dev_init failed for domain 3, errno Permission denied
E/com.example.example: vendor/qcom/proprietary/commonsys-intf/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:2254: Error 0x57: open_dev (-1) failed for domain 3
E/com.example.example: vendor/qcom/proprietary/commonsys-intf/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1053: Error 0x57: remote_handle64_open failed for file:///libsnpe_dsp_v66_domains_v2_skel.so?snpe_dsp_domains_v2_skel_handle_invoke&_modver=1.0&_dom=cdsp
```

And loading from Java with `System.loadLibrary("snpe_dsp_v66_domains_v2_skel");` doesn't work either, because as I noted, those libraries are built for completely different ABI and are supposed to be loaded by vendor's code

Comment: Your package must have a structure an you just want your library files to be copied to some location, right? If yes, then maybe you can run commands for that from your mk file https://stackoverflow.com/a/14396383/4688321.

Comment: @kiner_shah yup that helped adding the libraries in the package, yet the vendor's code doesn't have permissions on those files, I added more info into the question

Comment: I think you should contact the vendor and ask them about this issue. Maybe you need to do something additional so that this permission issue doesn't occur.

Comment: @kiner_shah OK, thank you so much! Sorry for stealing your time. Please add you answers, so I can accept them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to (and should not) do anything in your Android.mk to ship prebuilt vendor libraries. Add those libraries to the `app/src/main/jniLibs/$ABI` directory, similar to how the asan libraries are packaged in https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/asan.